# PHP Hashed Pwd Not Being Inserted to Database

Tags: php, hash

I created a simple php script that grabs value from username and password from my I-Phone app. I am certain that it grabs the correct username and password because it inserts the correct username and password to the database. However, when I tried to hash my password before inserting into the database, it failed to work.

Script is below. the $query statement doesn't go through, and I have no idea why.
Thank you!

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    @ob_start();

    $host='localhost';
    $user='root';
    $pass='root';
    $db_name="deep_freeze"; 

    $connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass, $db_name);

    $username_p = $_POST['username'];
    $password_p = $_POST['password'];
    // Hash the password.  $hashedPassword will be a 60-character string.
    $hashPwd = mysql_real_escape_string(password_hash('hello', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

    if(!$connection){
        die('Connection Failed');
    }
    else{
        $dbconnect = @mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_name);

        if(!$dbconnect){
            die('Could not connect to Database');
        }
        else{
            //echo $hashPwd;
            $query = "INSERT INTO deep_freeze VALUES ('$username_p','$hashPwd')";
            mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysql_error());

            echo 'Successfully added.';
            echo $query;
            echo $username_p.$password_p;
        }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: You are using mysqli for connection and using mysql_real_escape_string  for escaping string.

Comment: Don't mix mysql_* and mysqli_* functions. Also don't use mysql_* functions.

Comment: What length has the password in database? If your hash length is 100 chars and in your database you've set field to `varchar(80)`, password is truncated. Also, as said above, use only mysqli_* function, not mysql_*

Comment: That solved it, thanks!!!

Comment: Can you explain what was your problem? It could avoid an other people to ask the same question. Also, if one of us has said the answer it will post it as answer.

Comment: The issue was that in my database, I set my domain to be varchar(20). However, the hash was longer than 20 character. Thus, it wasn't saving. I changed the domain of password to be varchar(300) and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you said the length of your hash is 60 chars (according to password_hash method), so in your database your have to set your field at least with a length of 60 `varchar(60)`.

Note that if your database field length is less than 60, your password will be truncated on insert.

See [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) documentation.